# Really not support async setState of React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know `React Hooks` do not support synchronous methods like async/await.

I have to process the next process only if the `setState of the hooks` is synchronized and the value is successfully stored.

In the case of the original `this.setState({..})`, I used the callback to do the following, but what should I do `hooks setState`?

for the example,

```
export const FirstComponent = () => {
    const [peopleList, setPeopleList] = useState(null)
    const [myList, setMyList] = useState(null)

    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(gql(GQL_GET_PEOPLE_LIST)

    useEffect(() => {
        const onCompleted = data => {
            setPeopleList(data.list)
       }

       if (!loading) {
          onCompleted(data)
       }
    }, [data, loading, error])

    ...

    const onChangeMyList = id => {
        setMyList(peopleList.filter(x => x.id === id)
          .map(x => x.item.originalList.lists) // <- This must be completed first!!
        openModal(true) // <- Then, it has to be executed!
    }

    ...

    return (
      <div>
        <p onClick={() => onChangeMyList(id)}>Click!</p>
      <div>
    )
}
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: This is when [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't even need a `useEffect()`.

Since you're inside an event handler `onClick={() => onChangeMyList(id)}` when you're changing your list, React will automatically batch any `setState()` calls updates by default. It means the next render will happen when all states have already been updated. I don't know how you're opening your modal, but you could do something like this:

```js
function App() {

  const [myList, setMyList] = React.useState(['a','b','c']);
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setMyList(['a','b','c','d','e','f']);
    setOpenModal(true);
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div><b>myList: </b>{myList}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to change list and open modal</button>
      {openModal &&
        <div><b>I am Modal.</b> I was rendered together with the list: {myList}</div>
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be like this:

```
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => { if (modalOpen) openModal(true); }, [modalOpen]);
```

And later instead of calling openModal(true), you would call setModalOpen(true);